# How can I mirror a Multidimmensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, mirroring

I need to be able to mirror a multidimensional array that changes in size.  I'm currently hard coding for each particular array size and it is horribly inefficient.

Example:

```
Arr1 { 1 2 3               Arr2 { 1 2
       4 5 6                      3 4
       7 8 9 }                    5 6 }
```

Mirrored:

```
     { 3 2 1                    { 2 1
       6 5 4                      4 3
       9 8 7 }                    6 5 }
```

Arrays range in size from 2x5 to 4x10.

Comment: What logic are you using on that second array

Comment: Are you trying to modify the original array -- like, `Arr1` was `[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]` before, so will now be `[ [3,2,1], [6,5,4], [9,8,7] ]`? Or are you trying to create a copy of the array -- like `Arr1` is `[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]`, so you need `mirrored_Arr` to be `[ [3,2,1], [6,5,4], [9,8,7] ]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so all you need is a horizontal mirror.
I suppose that your array contains an array for every line,
so that means that you just need to reverse every row.

```
for(var i=0;i<multiarr.length;i++){
   multiarr[i].reverse();
}
```

or even better

```
multiarr.map(function(arr){return arr.reverse();});
```

Comment: I thought of that after writing the first answer. A lot of people are overcomplicating their code with loops to edit an array, when they can just use map()

Comment: Your example with `map` is a bit misleading, since it doesn't make it obvious that the callback is being applied for its side effects. (The `return`, in particular, is a stroke of obfuscation.) Sometimes that can't be helped, but in this case I think `multiarr.forEach(function(arr) { arr.reverse(); })` would be much clearer.

Comment: what's the browser support for foreach? When I needed it, I've always used the jQuery equivalent $.each

Comment: I knew I was over-thinking it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
For each of the lines:
    For i = 0 to width/2:
        arr[line][i] <-> arr[line][width - i]
```

Shouldn't that work?

Comment: it should indeed, but js has a built in reverse() function.